# MySQL (InnoDB) deadlock

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, deadlock

We are struggling with one deadlock which is occuring multiple times a day in our production environment.

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-12-27 19:07:34 7fcef1959700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2125001468, ACTIVE 2 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1

LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1

MySQL thread id 42190185, OS thread handle 0x7fcffc0b1700, query id 918842488 --- updating

UPDATE synchronization SET service_synchronized_at = NULL WHERE id = 116212

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 615 page no 288 n bits 528 index `PRIMARY` of table `app`.`synchronization` trx table locks 1 total table locks 2  trx id 2125001468 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 2 wait time before grant 0 

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2125001355, ACTIVE 5 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
25216 lock struct(s), heap size 3683880, 5297668 row lock(s), undo log entries 94

MySQL thread id 42189517, OS thread handle 0x7fcef1959700, query id 918842042 --- updating

UPDATE synchronization s SET s.service_synchronized_at = now() WHERE s.service_synchronized_at IS NULL AND s.user_id IN (* time consuming select to determine which users should be updated *)

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 615 page no 288 n bits 528 index `PRIMARY` of table `app`.`synchronization` trx table locks 2 total table locks 2  trx id 2125001355 lock_mode X lock hold time 3 wait time before grant 0 

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 615 page no 2313 n bits 472 index `PRIMARY` of table `app`.`synchronization` trx table locks 2 total table locks 2  trx id 2125001355 lock_mode X waiting lock hold time 0 wait time before grant 0 

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

In one query I want to set `service_synchronized_at = NULL`. service_synchronized_at is always not null in first query before update.

In second query I add a where condition `s.service_synchronized_at IS NULL` thinking it would result in non-locking rows with not null values. Guess I was wrong.

The table has only primary index on `id` and unique constraint on `user_id` (and of course foreign key on `user_id`).

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I guess from the information you have given that you are trying to set _service_synchronised_at_ to NULL at regular intervals, and "time consuming select to determine which users should be updated" sometimes take so long that it's still running when the next invalidation is executed.

Comment: I suggest optimising your "time consuming select" (if possible) and storing the results into a temporary table, which you then join to _synchronisation_ to perform the update. This will minimise the lock duration.

Comment: @grahamj42 I always thought about deadlock as "transaction A needs holds resource 1 and needs resource 2 and transaction B holds resource 2 and needs resource 1". So deadlock can be achieved if one transaction holds table for too long? The time consuming select takes 4s. Can I achieve implicit creation of temporary table by wrapping the select with another select? (I read somewhere that MySQL will create temporary tables in such cases).

Comment: There are other causes of deadlocks.  Live with it.  Plan on re-executing the `UPDATE` when it is zapped with a deadlock.

Comment: I have another question. Shoulnt be mysql smart enough to lock table synchronization after *time consuming select* is executed? Dont see any reason why the table should be locked while the select is executed.

Comment: Looking in more detail, transaction 1 is waiting to lock the same row that transaction 2 holds, but transaction 2 is waiting on another lock. I suspect that there is another transaction involved which the error message doesn't show. As shown, it's not a deadlock between transactions 1 and 2. MySQL reference explaining why index locks are taken : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html